# HTTP Content-Type header to serve a font file

Tags: http, fonts, http-headers, header

I'm making an online [EOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_OpenType) converter...

What 'Content-Type' header should I set to serve a font file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded%5FOpenType) you linked to says `application/vnd.ms-fontobject`. That’s also the [media type that’s registered for the file extension `.eot` at the IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.ms-fontobject).